# Only the button on the first row is working in a table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I have an MVC Application that returns items from the model and there is a button added on the table to each row, the problem is that only the first item that is working perfectly the rest doesn't even call the method. I have done my research with no luck. here is the code on my view. is there something that I am doing wrong? Please help.

```
<section class="container">
    <section class="panel">
        <section class="panel-heading panel-border-danger ">
            <h2 class="panel-heading-text ">
                <i></i>  Script Management
            </h2>
        </section>
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <section >

            <table class="table table-responsive" id="tblScripManager">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.scriptName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.logFileName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AllowToRun)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.scriptdescription)
                        </th>
                        <th> Last Run </th>
                        <th> Time Taken</th>
                        <th> Errors </th>
                        <th> Re-Run </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.scriptName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.logFileName)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AllowToRun)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.scriptdescription)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastRun)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeTaken)
                            </td>

                            @if (item.Errors == "No Errors")
                            {
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Errors)</td>

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td style="cursor:pointer"> <a id="myBtn" class="btn-group">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Errors)</a></td>
                            }

                            <td>
                                <input id="btnRun" type="button" value="Run Script" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Script", "RunScript")?id=' + document.getElementById('@item.scriptId').value" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                            <!-- Modal content -->
                            <div class="modal-content" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:30px; left: 50px; top: 70px; width: 70%; height: 50%; ">
                                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <p style="line-break:strict">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ErrorList)</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>

    </section>

</section>



<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnRun").click(function () {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("RunScript")', { scriptId: '4' }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //$("#run").val(data);
            });
        });

    });


    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    $('.modal').click(function () {
        $('#my-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

`

Comment: You have duplicate id's for the button. Remove the hard coded id from the loop and use a css class selector.

Comment: Also, you have code which will navigate to the `/Scripts/RunScript` action method on the click event, while you have some click event handler registered for making some ajax call. It does not make sense!. What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: I am trying to call the RunScript method on my controller.

Comment: You want to do it via ajax ? In that case why do you have the `onclick` event in the button ?

Comment: I have removed the one on the button ond only using the one on ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is generating **a button with `btnRun` as Id, for each iteration of the loop**. That means, If your Model is a collection of 10 items, your code will generate 10 buttons, all with the same `Id` value.

Element's Id' should be unique. The markup generated by your current code in invalid because it generates more than one element same `Id` attribute value.

The jquery selector expression `$("#btnRun")` will return you the first item matching the selector expression. In  this case you will get the first item even though you are clicking the button in a different row.

You can remove the `Id` attribute on the button and wire up the click event with the a more generic jquery selector (ex : css class selector/name selector/ data attribute selector etc)

Here is an example, where i am adding an html5 data attribute to the button and storing the url with(route values) to the `RunScript` action method.

```
<td>
    <button  data-url="@Url.Action("RunScript", "Script",
                                     new {scriptId = item.scriptId})"> Run Script</button>
</td>
```

And you will wire up the click event to input element's which has a `data-url` attribute

```
$(function () {

    $("button[data-url]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

});
```

Since we used the `Url.Action` helper inside the razor view to generate the url, now your javascript code can be easily moved to an external js file as well.

My personal prefer

Comment: Can I trouble you one more time,  I also have an <a><a> on the same view, that opens a modal pop up, it also have the same problem, it works only on the first row, I have tried fixing it.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant part of code, it is hard to tell! I suggest you create a new question with the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you. It is on the same view, it the one above the button.@if (item.Errors == "No Errors")
                            {
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Errors)</td>

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td style="cursor:pointer"> <a id="myBtn" class="btn-group">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Errors)</a></td>
                            }"

Comment: `id="myBtn"` inside the loop again ?? I think you should read the answer again

Answer (score 2):

The button id is not unique. Generate a unique id like with the below and it should be ok.

I would also invoke the post using Jquery and css selector.

```
 var itemCount = 0;

    @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <tr>

             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.scriptName)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.logFileName)
             </td>

             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AllowToRun)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.scriptdescription)
             </td>

             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastRun)
             </td>

             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeTaken)
             </td>

             @if (item.Errors == "No Errors")
             {
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Errors)</td>

             }
             else
             {
                 <td style="cursor:pointer"> <a id="myBtn" class="btn-group">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Errors)</a></td>
             }

             @{var buttonid = "btnRun" + itemCount};

             <td>
                <input id="@buttonid" type="button" class="MyButton" value="Run Script" data-scriptid="@item.scriptId"/>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <div id="myModal" class="modal">

             <!-- Modal content -->
             <div class="modal-content" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:30px; left: 50px; top: 70px; width: 70%; height: 50%; ">
                 <span class="close">&times;</span>
                 <p style="line-break:strict">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ErrorList)</p>
             </div>
         </div>

        itemCount++;
    }
```

Create a class called "MyButton" or whatever you want too. Then capture the click with JQuery. Extract the script id from the data attribute and post it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.MyButton', function () {

    var scriptid = $(this).data("scriptid");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Script/RunScript/",
        data: {id:scriptid}
    });

});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but all buttons just stopped working instead.:(

Comment: Hello, I've updated my answer. Use the data attribute to hold your script id on each button, then use JQuery with a css selector to capture the button click and invoke the post.

Comment: What's not working. What happens when you debug the js? Can you put an alert in to confirm that the click event is firing? Are there any errors in the developer tools window?